# ¿Cómo buscar la posición de elementos repetidos en diferentes columnas, para realizar operaciones con sus respectivas posiciones?

Tags: python, lista

Saludos:

Tengo una problemática y me gustaría saber sus  comentarios, quiero buscar la posición de un elemento repetido en la columna 0 y en la columna 1  de una matriz "X" y sumar su respectivos valores de la columna 2 en la diagonal principal de una nueva matriz "z". Los elementos fuera de la diagonal principal de la matriz "z" deben ser los elementos comunes entre la columna 0 y la columna 1. Presento una matriz a modo de ejemplo:

```
        0 1 2
x=  0 [[1,2,3],
    1  [1,3,5],
    2  [3,2,6]]
```

En este caso el número 1 se repite en el renglón 0  y en el renglón 1 de la columna 0 y columna 1. Entonces, el valor de la diagonal principal en la matriz "z" debe ser la suma de los respectivos valores en la columna 2, es decir 3+5. Los valores fuera de la diagonal principal en la matriz "z" deben ser 3 y 5 respectivamente. El número dos se repite en el renglón 0 y en el renglón 2. Entonces, el valor de la diagonal principal de la matriz "z", debe ser la suma de los valores de la columna 2, es decir 3+6. Los respectivos valores fuera de la diagonal son 3 y 6. Para ejemplificar lo anterior, presento la matriz de solución:

```
      0    1    2
z=[[3+5,   3,   5],
   [  3, 3+6,   6],
   [  5,   6, 5+6]]
```

Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta ya que, tal cual está, no se entiende muy bien tu propósito. Intenta usar el formateo de código para escribir correctamente las matrices y las salidas que deseas (mira aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el dominio del problema está bien definido, una solución al problema que planteas podría ser éste:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [[1, 2, 3],
     [1, 3, 5],
     [3, 2, 6]]

# combinaciones de dos en dos
combs = list(combinations(x, 2))

aux = [
  [[x+y,   x,   y] for ([i, _, x], [j, _, y]) in combs if i == j],
  [[  x, x+y,   y] for ([_, i, x], [_, j, y]) in combs if i == j],
  [[  x,   y, x+y] for ([i, j, x], [k, v, y]) in combs if i == v or j == k]
]

# concatenación de listas
result = sum(aux, [])

print(result)
```

Si no es la solución que necesitas, tal vez deberías explicar mejor el problema.